# How to suggest words when a user types letters related in tkinter

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I want to suggest the user certain words if he types something related to it in an entry. So, I will have a list of words. When the user types something similar to a certain word in the list, the code will automatically suggest that word from the list in a drop down menu. Is there any way to make this happen?

Comment: You want to research "fuzzy matching" or "Word embedding".

Comment: You need to be more specific about the question. Do you already have a function that returns matching words and you need to know how to display them, or do you already have a way to display them but don't know how to compute them? If you have neither, than this question is just far too broad.

Comment: Bryan is largely right. though you might find this [autocomplete entry](https://gist.github.com/samuelkazeem/f3e7780de569f0cba5fd3eab469749a4) solves your problem.